# Push a commit to Gitlab and trigger the CI/CD pipelines using he API and a Project Access Token

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I'm trying to add a commit to my repo using a project access token and the gitlab API, and trigger the CI/CD pipelines from the commit.

Currently I can successfully create the commit using the API but the pipeline errors saying:

> The pipeline failed due to the user not being verified

I've tried:

1. granting the project access token all the permissions
2. setting the project access token role to `Owner`
3. Adding my email and name to the commit, (commit shows that I created it but the pipeline knows it was the project access token that tried to trigger it)

All to no effect.

I want to use a project access token to limit the access the token has to just one project, using a personal access token works because that is seen as being committed by me, a verified user. But this allows access to everything the user has access to, something I don't want to do.

The project access tokens create their own service user, is there an additional step I'm missing to get the project access token user verified?

Answer (score 0):

https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/05/17/prevent-crypto-mining-abuse/

the team member will need to validate their account or alternatively you can disable shared runners in the related projects.